# Django: Assign default value using model method (using self)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm looking to assign a default value using a method inside model:

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    # attributes ...

    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id) + ". " + self.title

    def class_name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

    discussion_type = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = self.class_name())

class TechDiscussion(Discussion):
    # ...

class ScienceDiscussion(Discussion):
    # ...
```

In my Django app, users can only create science or tech discussions. Thus `discussion_type` should be either `"TechDiscussion"` or `"ScienceDiscussion"`.

Server returns error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`, referring to the default value assigned to `discussion_type`.

Comment: simple solution is override the save method of the `Super` model.

Comment: @BearBrown thanks it worked. This seems to be a standard, documented way of adding functionality upon saving a model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bear Brown suggested in the comment a solution would be to override the `save()` method of the `Discussion` class, also documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods). I removed the `discussion_type` assignment and added the override, as in the documentation:

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    # attributes ...

    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id) + ". " + self.title

    def class_name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.call_type = self.class_name()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `if not self.call_type:` other way you have not default but constant.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work as the Discussion model will have its own database table - so you need to make it abstract. It will still try to access self where there is no object, so replace this with the class name. And it shall not evaluate the function when assigning just when saving so just add the function object there (without brackets).

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    # attributes ...

    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id) + ". " + self.title

    def class_name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

   discussion_type = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = Discussion.class_name)

   class Meta:
       abstract = True
```

However, I have not tested this if this really works.

Comment: Now I get the error: `NameError: name 'Discussion' is not defined`